# Hide iframe partially in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have main.jsp page which has two frames here code is

```
 <body>
<div><a href="#" onClick="somthingJS();"> hide</a></div>
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="height:100%"><iframe name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" src="leftnavigation.jsp" height="600" width="200" frameborder="0"></iframe></td>

    <td style="height:100%"><iframe name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" src="news.jsp"  height="600" width="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"> </iframe></td>
</tr>       
</tr>   

</table>
</body>
```

and i need to hide my **leftFrame**.  on hide lable where onclick method do something to hide my iframe
but not all it must get hidden up to 90 percent using Jquery 
how I can hide & show by clicking on hide..

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Just checking in to make sure it's still 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "hide up to 90" - as opacity change to 20%? then:
Use jquery `.fadeTo`
here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/rnAyh/

If you want to change with you might check this: http://jsfiddle.net/rnAyh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the widths of the iframes?

```
(function() {
  var toggle = false,
      frames = [document.getElementById('leftFrame'),document.getElementById('mainFrame')];
  window.somethingJS = function() {
    frames[0].setAttribute("width",toggle ? 200 : 20);
    frames[1].setAttribute("width",toggle ? 1000 : 1180);
    toggle = !toggle;
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I not sure I entirely understood what you were trying to do, but from the title, it seems to me that you want to clip an iframe. Try the CSS iframe property.

```
.iframe-to-crop {
    clip: rect(0px,50px,0px,0px);
}
```

This will 'cut off' 50px of the right side of the iframe.
Check [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of the left frame to `opacity: 0.1` - just change `somethingJS();` to

```
document.getElementById('leftFrame').style.opacity = 0.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below code should , find my comments inline for explanation.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
           /*
            attr() if element height is needed if set, 
            css() if style element used
            */

            function somethingJS(){
                var iHeight=$('#leftFrame').attr("height");
               iHeight=(!isNaN(iHeight))?600:iHeight;
               $('#leftFrame').attr("height",iHeight-iHeight*(90/100));
            }

        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- In your original code href="#" will create problems in IE , so either attach the event in jquery onload or use the below code -->    
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="somethingJS()"> hide</a>    
    </div>
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="height:100%"><iframe name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" src="12197789.html" height="600" width="200" frameborder="1"></iframe></td>

    <td style="height:100%"><iframe name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" src="12197789.html" height="600" width="1000" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto"> </iframe></td>
</tr>       
</table>
</body>
</html>
```